# Copy a static array to host in managedCUDA

Tags: c#, managed-cuda

I've declared a static array in kernel.cu file

```
__device__ int myStaticArray[5];
```

I can modify this array from host using

```
myKernel.SetConstantVariable("myStaticArray", new int[]{1,2,3,4,5});
```

After a few processing, I want to copy this array to host, how can I do so?

**EDIT1**: I noticed that the array will be reset every time when I run a new kernel. I cannot use that array to keep intermediate values to be used in the next kernel. Is it possible to keep those values in static ways?

**EDIT2**: The problem in **EDIT1** occur because I load multiple kernels using LoadKernelPTX. The correct way is to load module once, then construct multiple kernels from that module. (as suggested in https://github.com/kunzmi/managedCuda/wiki/CudaKernel) This way, I can have shared static array/variable across multiple kernels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you declare the array as `__device__ __constant__ int myStaticArray[5];` and treat it as a constant array (i.e. you don't write to it). Then you can initialize the values from host using `myKernel.SetConstantVariable(...)`.

Or you you keep it as an `__device__ int myStaticArray[5];`, then you can declare a `CudaDeviceVariable` using the constructor `CudaDeviceVariable(CUmodule module, string name)` that gathers the pointer to that static variable. You can then do any copy-to-host or copy-to-device as usual.

Note that names in Cuda get mangled if the variable is not declared as `extern "C"`, so you might have to look up the full mangled name in the PTX-file.